# PostgreSQL count data based on grouped data

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a database that looks like this

```
users
email             name    state       id
bill@domain.com   Bill    CA           1
                  Susan   WY           2
jill@domain.com   Jill    CA           3
phil@domain.com   Phil    WY           4
```

You'll notice that Susan does not have an email.

I'm trying to get a count of records per state, then a total number of non null emails for each state.

I was able to get the total count of states like this:

`SELECT state, COUNT(*) as count FROM users GROUP BY state`

That works great.

Then I tried getting the total number of emails like this:

`SELECT state, COUNT(*) as count, COUNT(SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IS NOT NULL) as email_count FROM users GROUP BY state`

But that returned a parse syntax error.

I'm trying to get a return dataset like this:

```
[
  {state: 'CA', count: 2, email_count: 2},
  {state: 'WY', count: 2, email_count: 1}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
SELECT 
    state,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN email is not null then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_email_not_null
FROM users 
GROUP BY state
```

It will give you your intended output.